# Cypress unable to run in Jenkins?

Tags: javascript, testing, jenkins-pipeline, cypress

I'm trying to run the cypress test with Jenkins in my workplace. Due to Proxy issue I have uploaded my local node modules in s3 and before running the test I will download those modules and then run the test using this command.

But I'm getting below error Which I haven't understood. Can someone please explain what's wrong here?

```
CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER=./cypress-cache ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --headless --browser chrome --spec cypress/integration/api/api-test.spec.ts
```

```
The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing.

We expected the binary to be installed here: /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/test-builds/cypress-ui-test-build/cypress-cache/6.1.0/Cypress/Cypress

Reasons it may be missing:

- You're caching 'node_modules' but are not caching this path: /home/jenkins/.cache/Cypress
- You ran 'npm install' at an earlier build step but did not persist: /home/jenkins/.cache/Cypress

Properly caching the binary will fix this error and avoid downloading and unzipping Cypress.

Alternatively, you can run 'cypress install' to download the binary again.

https://on.cypress.io/not-installed-ci-error

----------

Platform: linux (Debian- 9.9)
Cypress Version: 6.1.0
```

If I try ./node_modules/.bin/cypress --version

```
Cypress package version: 6.1.0
Cypress binary version: not installed
```

Comment: I think that what the error is saying is that you don't have cypress installed. I used cypress before in Jenkins, but we always did `npm install` for every build and cyppress was a dev dependency. the error states "We expected the binary to be installed here" and even mentions that running `npm install` might fix it

Comment: @rmjoia I don't have access to server so I'm looking other ways to install cypress binary rather then running npm install.

Comment: I had a similar issue multiple times but on my local machine, the AV was removing the binary file, I tried with previous versions and worked fine, did you try with one or more previous versions?

Comment: yep, my old version seem to work. But since I have updated by dependencies I need to use new version. Were you able to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like indeed you have uploaded all the node_modules, but you didn't upload Cypress itself.
Have you tried to run `npm install` or `cypress install`?

Besides, just FYI, Jenkins is only a continuous integration tool. It helps you manage tasks. All the commands still just run on your server :)

Comment: Cypress is installed and I can see it's version. Here, the issue is Cypress binary version is not found. Since I don't have access to server I'm looking ways to update cypress binary version rather than using npm install/ cypress install

Answer (score 0):

We need to upload the cypress binary cache folder as well inorder to run the cypress in jenkins. Make sure you upload node_modules and cypress cache folder to run the cypress in jenkins :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).